# Manage a queue by sorting a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sorting, optimization

I have a queue of users and jobs. Only one job can be performed at a time.

```
User       |   Job ID   |   Job Status
------------------------------------------
A          |      1     |   Waiting
A          |      2     |   Waiting
B          |      3     |   Done
B          |      4     |   Waiting
B          |      5     |   Waiting
C          |      6     |   Done
C          |      7     |   Done
C          |      8     |   Waiting
```

I would like to query the list to prioritise jobs to try and give all users an equal number of completed jobs. If one user has a lot of completed jobs, the queue should prioritise jobs by other users until other users have caught up.

In this case, A has no completed jobs so has the highest priority:

```
User  |   Completed Jobs
------------------------
A     |   0
B     |   1
C     |   2
```

So the head of the queue should be A. The second item in the queue should be a job by user A or user B, since by the time the second job was started, both users A and B will have had one job already completed. Once A and B have had two jobs each completed, they are equal in priority to user C.

```
User  |   Job ID  |  User Completed Jobs  |  Priority
-----------------------------------------------------
A     |   1       |  0                 0  |  1
B     |   3       |  1                 1  |  2
A     |   2       |  0 + 1             1  |  3
B     |   5       |  1 + 1             2  |  4
C     |   8       |  2                 2  |  5
```

The User Completed Jobs column is complicated though, because to calculate its value you need to consider everything ahead of it in the queue.

So, is there a nice way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: So do you want to to select the next job (ordered by priority) or do you want to see a list of all jobs, ordered by priority?

Comment: Ideally list all jobs ordered by priority